# Matrix operation: simplifying a simple expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, self-learning

Let $X$ and $\mu$ are $p$ dimensional vector and $\Sigma$ $p\times p$ dimensional matrix. I have to simplify the following expression.

$-\frac{1}{2}(X-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(X-\mu)$

$=-\frac{1}{2}(X^T-\mu^T)\Sigma^{-1}(X-\mu)$

$=-\frac{1}{2}(X^T\Sigma^{-1}X-X^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu-\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}X+\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu)$

But the result will be:

$-\frac{1}{2}(X-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(X-\mu)=-\frac{1}{2}X^T\Sigma^{-1}X+X^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu-\frac{1}{2}\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu.$

Comment: The two cross terms are just real numbers, so they are symmetric and you can take the transpose and combine them

Comment: Key word is scalar.

Comment: Note that
$$
X^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu = [X^T \Sigma^{-1}\mu]^T = \mu^T (\Sigma^{-1})^T X^{TT}.
$$